# R pander doesn't show result with accentuated character

Tags: r, pander

I've worked for some months with pander/rmarkdown/rstudio without problem, but on this new machine, something as simple as

```
library(pander)
cars$test="qsdféé"
pander(cars)
```

give me back "Error in table.expand(x, t.width, justify, sep.col) : 
  basic_string::_S_create"

I don't understand, because on my previous machine, it works without a flaw. 
Same pander version (0.6.0), same configuration of Rstudio (default encoding utf-8), windows 7 on both sides.

It's quite strange because pander has no problem if I have only one accentuated character (car$test="qsdfé") but it's the second that trigger the problem.

In rmarkdown, it makes the compiler stop instantly, with no error message.

Comment: I'd compare the output of `sessionInfo()` or rather `devtools::session_info()` on the two computers to see what's different. It could be R version, locale or  eg Rcpp versions.

Comment: Thank you very much, I hadn't thought about R Version. I downgraded to R 3.3, and now it's fine. It seems to be a 3.4 bug, is there anywhere I should report this ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, which doesn't have a solution (other than reverting R-version) as of now. There is an open issue on github: [Link](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/issues/296)

Issue #296